# exim on Amazon AMI via yum

Tags: amazon-ec2, exim

I'm having trouble figuring out `yum`, `rpm`, and `exim4`.

All I want to do is

```
yum install exim4
```

`yum` has been good to me in the past, smoothly fetching all packages and dependencies required to run the program I desire.

But not this time.  `exim4` wasn't included in the `amzn-main` package apparently.

```
amzn-main/latest
amzn-updates/latest
No package exim4 available.
```

Now I don't want any fish.  I want to learn how to use the dadgam `yum` fishing rod.

- I don't know *where* to get the command to install `exim4` via `yum`.
- I don't know how to expand the places my Linux instance is looking (besides just `amzn-main`) to actually find the `exim4` `yum` package

  - I don't know whether it is *safe* to look in other places for packages for my ec2 instance other than `amzn-main`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amazon Linux doesn't include exim in its [packages](http://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/2013.09-packages/) at all. Use a different MTA.

Comment: I see, so `postfix` or `sendmail` are options for me, but not `exim`.  Does this mean `exim` just _isn't available_ for me as a Linux AMI user?  That seems a bit oppressive.

Comment: Why? Are you _attached_ to exim? In any case, if you have a problem with Amazon's choice of packages to ship, you have to complain to Amazon...

Comment: Somebody recommended `exim` -- I suppose they should all be roughly eq. looking at [a comparison](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_mail_servers).  I tried installing `sendmail` and apparently it is already installed on AMI servers.. so that was cool.

Comment: Or if you know how to build RPM's, get a recent exim src.rpm and rebuild it. It's not always easy, it depends how much rpm macro customization is done by AMI and/or the src rpm you grabbed. If you have never rebuilt RPM's before, I don't advise it.

Answer (score 2):

If you enable the repository [EPEL](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL), then you can install exim via yum. Here's are [Amazon's instructions](https://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/faqs/#epel):

> Modify /etc/yum.repos.d/epel.repo. Under the section marked [epel],
>   change enabled=0 to enabled=1.
>
> To temporarily enable the EPEL 6 repository, use the yum command line
>   option --enablerepo=epel.
>
> Please note that the Amazon Linux AMI repositories are configured with
>   a higher priority than any third-party repositories. The reason for
>   this is because there are several packages that are part of the Amazon
>   Linux AMI that are also in third-party repositories, and we want to
>   make sure that the Amazon Linux AMI version is installed in the
>   default case.

Enabling EPEL is relatively safe, since according to the [FAQ](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL/FAQ#How_is_EPEL_different_from_other_third_party_repositories_for_RHEL_and_derivatives.3F) "EPEL is purely a complementary add-on repository and does not replace packages in RHEL or layered products."

Comment: Warning: EPEL packages are not built or tested for Amazon Linux and may or may not work.

Answer (score 2):

These days [exim is included](https://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/2018-03-packages/), so no need for third party repos. You can simply `yum install exim`.

Answer (score -1):

enable this:

```
sudo yum install -y https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm
```

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-enable-epel/

Once that is installed, you don't need --enablerepo=epel on each yum command.  It's enabled for good.

```
$ yum list available | grep exim
```

This shows that you are installing exim 4.90 (latest is 4.91, I don't see that available.)

finally:

```
$ sudo yum install exim
```

That's it.
......

Comment: Warning: EPEL packages are not built or tested for Amazon Linux and may or may not work.